# Controlling the spaces between paragraphs

Tags: spacing

In the [IEEE latex package](http://www.ieee.org/documents/windows_latex_template.zip), I see that the paragraph spacing is set to zero (.cls file)

```
% Controls the spacing between paragraphs in lists. 
% IEEE does not increase spacing before or after paragraphs 
% so this is also zero. 
% With IEEEtran.cls, global changes to
% this value DO affect lists (but not IED lists).
\parsep             \z@
```

However, in the output PDF file, I see some spacings.

[image]

Why?

Comment: I haven't used the IEEE latex package, but usually I would set parsep in the preamble via ``\setlength{\parsep}{0pt)``. Can you try if that works?

Comment: My bad, had a typo. The 0pt should be in {}-type brackets, not in regular brackets. So ``\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}``

Comment: `\parsep` is about paragraph spacing inside *lists*, not about normal paragraphs, for which the parameter is `\parskip`, usually set to `0pt plus 0.1pt`. Setting `\parskip` to zero will probably produce underfull boxes and columns with unequal heights.

Comment: @AndrewCashner No, I meant `\parskip`. If there's no flexible glue in a column and the text height is not computed correctly, underfull boxes and unbalanced columns will appear.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to answer your question without knowing your setup. If you have chosen the option `twoside`, you also have turned on `flushbottom` I presume, and then LaTeX will add space also between the paragraphs to stretch the page.

Try the option `oneside`, or add the command `\raggedbottom` as the last command in the preamble.

The class files defines `\parskip` as:

```
\parskip 0ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex
```

so check your code and packages that you not unintentionally have altered this definition.

Comment: If you download the package and compile the bare_conf.tex, you will see the issue

Comment: @mahmood I am not able to install the class on my computer now.